# ASP.NET core Sitefinity application not running

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm working on a Sitefinity ASP.NET application. I've been following the documentation explicitly from [https://www.progress.com/documentation/...](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/setup-the-asp.net-core-renderer). Everything seemed to be going great until I ran the renderer.

Aside from the setup/installation of the app itself, the following files had to be updated.

`launchSettings.json`, `Program.cs` and `appsettings.json`

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9296",
      "sslPort": 44337
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Renderer": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

using Progress.Sitefinity.AspNetCore;
using Progress.Sitefinity.AspNetCore.FormWidgets;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddSitefinity();
builder.Services.AddViewComponentModels();
builder.Services.AddFormViewComponentModels();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseSitefinity();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapSitefinityEndpoints();
});

app.Run();
```

The issue seems to be with the following file. The documentation (linked above) says to paste in the code below:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Sitefinity": {
    "Url": "https://yoursitefinitywebsiteurl",
    "WebServicePath": "api/default"
  }
}
```

When I try to run the application, this is what I get, which is expected, but when I change out the `Sitefinity >> Url` value (https://localhost:5001, http://localhost:5000), but I still get a dead page.
[image]

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you change it to simply: `https://localhost:5001`?

Comment: I get a message that says, "This page cannot be found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting:

> "Sitefinity": {
> "Url": "https://yoursitefinitywebsiteurl",..

should point to the URL of your standard Sitefinity web site (SitefinityWebApp).

Have you setup one in IIS?

Does it run?

This video might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PakWXc3Efg8 on how to set it up using the CLI.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm not publishing the site right now. I'm just trying to build it locally first. I have not set up anything in IIS. It's not supported in this version of Sitefinity's ASP.NET core.

Comment: No no no, you still need to setup the standard sitefinity site, locally in IIS is fine. The .net core renderer app will need to connect to that site and use that site's API endpoint in order to get the data from. You can't have just the .net core renderer, it is useless without the actual sitefinity app and its backend

Comment: Just watched the video and I think it might save me, but now I'm seeing this: [https://i.imgur.com/iYCpyTx.png](https://i.imgur.com/iYCpyTx.png). Is this likely a local firewall issue?

Comment: does your sitefinity site runs fine now? did you allow Everyone access to the api endpoint?

Comment: No. I'm developing locally first before I push to a staging area. I ran into a firewall issue though.